# rospy.Publisher: what's a good choice for queue_size?

Tags: ros, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We just switched over to using Indigo, and noticed the warnings about using rospy.Publisher without specifying a queue_size. I've read [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) and I can see that it's a fabulous idea to specify this value. What's a good value to use, and how do I know if I've picked a reasonable number?

Thanks,

Rick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190357/rospy.publisher:-what%27s-a-good-choice-for-queue_size?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The queue size is a balance between latency and completeness. If your usage only wants the latest data a small queue size is appropriate. If your application would rather have more complete information a larger queue size is preferred.

Note it will only be an issue if your topic backs up. Another consideration is if the publisher will be pushing multiple messages close together make sure the queue is big enough to hold the whole batch if you don't want losses.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-08-17**:
Thanks Tully,

Rick

**Comment by [Paddre](https://answers.ros.org/users/29218/paddre/) on 2017-07-22**:
Are there any performance or efficiency concerns connected to the queue size? I.e. does a smaller queue size save memory or is there no gain of a small queue size over a large queue size?